# Append object's values to specific span elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

From backend I'm sending a list of prices.

Like: `[70, 90, 100, 140, 200]`

I also have `<span>` elements with specific clases, inside a div:

```
<span class="price_50_units"></span>
<span class="price_100_units"></span>
<span class="price_200_units"></span>
<span class="price_300_units"></span>
<span class="price_500_units"></span>
```

I need to append these elements to it's specific span. The first element of the list will always correspond to the span with `class="price_50_units"`:

```
<span class="price_50_units">70</span> #should be the result for the first span.
```

The second element will always corresponde to the span with `class="price_100_units"` and so on.

```
<span class="price_100_units">90</span> #should be the result for the second span.
```

Right now I can put span elements with the values of the list inside a div with this code:

```
req.done(function (response) {
     $('#prices').empty();
     var prices = response.prices;
     var list = '';
     for (var j = 0; j < prices.length; j++) {
         list += "<span>" + prices[j] + "</span></br>";
         }
     $('#prices').html(list);

    });
```

This code will create new span elements, with the values from the list.

**But how to target span elements already present in html?**

I was thinking on something like this, but is not working:

```
 $('p').children('span .price_50_units').text(prices[1]);
```

Comment: Put a shared class on them, select based on the class, and then the setting of the elements index is a direct correlation to the array index.

Comment: `$('p').children('span.price_50_units').text(prices[1]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the index of the response and the index of the span is a direct correlation, then you can put a common class on the spans, and just set their texts based on the index.

```js
var responseData = [70, 90, 100, 140, 200];

$('.price').text(function(index){
  return responseData[index];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price price_50_units"></span>
<span class="price price_100_units"></span>
<span class="price price_200_units"></span>
<span class="price price_300_units"></span>
<span class="price price_500_units"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your spans are not always created in order, then maybe:

```js
// Your data
var respData = [70, 90, 100, 140, 200];
// Loop through
$.each(respData, function(index, value ) {
  // Check if element exists. PS change selector if needed
  if($('span.price_' + value + '_units').length) {
    // add the value to the span
    $('span.price_' + value + '_units').text(value);
  }
});
```

Comment: Error is inside StackOverFlow, when running the snippet: 

`{
  "message": "ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 16,
  "colno": 1
}`

Comment: @OmarGonzales I did not include the jquery library in my answer thats why you get that error. Add the code in your solution and try it out. Be sure to change the respData to match your variable with the result.